# Property 'markets' does not exist on type '{ markets: [Market]; } In typescript

Tags: typescript

When I'm trying to access `action.payload.markets`, it is giving me compile time error:

> Property 'markets' does not exist on type '{ markets: [Market]; } | {
>   market: Market; } | { error: any; }'.   Property 'markets' does not
>   exist on type '{ market: Market; }'.

Here is the code I am using.

market.actions.ts

```
export class LoadMarket implements Action {
  readonly type = MarketActionTypes.LoadMarket;
  constructor(public payload: {markets: [Market]}) {}
}

export class UpdateMarket implements Action {
  readonly type = MarketActionTypes.UpdateMarket;
  constructor(public payload: {market: Market}) {}
}
export class LoadMarketFailure implements Action {
  readonly type = MarketActionTypes.LoadMarketFailure;
  constructor(public payload: {error: any}) {}
}

export type MarketActions =
  | LoadMarket
  | UpdateMarket
  | LoadMarketFailure;
```

market.reducers.ts

```
export function marketReducer(state = initialState, action: MarketActions): MarketState {
  switch (action.type) {   
    case MarketActionTypes.LoadMarket: {
      return {
        ...state,
        markets: action.payload.markets, // this is giving compile time error.  Property 'markets' does not exist on type '{ markets: [Market]; } | { market: Market; } | { error: any; }'. Property 'markets' does not exist on type '{ market: Market; }'.
        error: null
      };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your payload can be one of three types:

- `{ markets: [Market]; }`
- `{ market: [Market]; }`
- `{ error: any }`

The compiler is warning you that it *might* not be the type you have assumed (the first one).

You should handle this by narrowing the type, which you can do with a type assertion.

Example custom type guard - you may want a deeper check than this...

```
function hasMarkets(input: MyUnionType): input is { markets: [Market]; } {
    return (!!(<any>input).markets); 
}
```

And here is an example without, and then with, the custom type guard:

```
const val1 = example.markets; // No

if (hasMarkets(example)) {
    const val2 = example.markets; // Yes
}
```

When you use the type guard, everything will be narrowed in the `if` as well as in the `else` if you have one (in your case, the else statement will be a union of the other two types). You can also use type guards with other conditional statements, not just ifs.

Comment: @RahulRai example added - it took a while to type. The payload could be any of the three types in the union type. When you use a type guard, you narrow it to the single type that you expect. This also handles cases where it isn't the type you expect and it is worth adding an `else` to handle those unexpected cases.